# I need to use $.getJSON in eclipse? how do I declare the import statement for jquery if .jar is in lib?

Tags: jquery, json, eclipse

need to get data, JSON data and other data from url. I need to call the function $.getJSON but it is undefined in my JSP because I need to have the proper import statement in the begining of the document, something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "lib/jquery/1.11.0.min.js">
```

The issue is that is not my jar file name. how do I link the src to the proper jar lib.

jar title location in lib

see example

need to get data, JSON data and other data from url. I need to call the function $.getJSON but it is undefined in my JSP because I need to have the proper import statement in the begining of the document, something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "lib/jquery/1.11.0.min.js">
```

The issue is that is not my jar file name. how do I link the src to the proper jar lib.

jar title location in lib

404 error for jquery.ui and 1.11 min js

Comment: Your jQuery file is in a `*.jar` file?

Comment: Java and JavaScript ARE NOT the same thing. I think you are mixing the concepts...

Comment: There is a jar file for the jquery library.  jquery.ui1.12.0.jar

Comment: normally a script language is used, and a src="/lib/jquery.1.12.0.min.js" is used. But it is not working for me. Whats the simplest way to use my $.getJSON command

Comment: Where did this jar come from? Where is it during your page's runtime?

Comment: So I have added the jquery.js to a javascript folder in WebContent. I imported the script but Jquery $ commands are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (which is a fact). All jar files located in lib needs to be added to the build path, then you can access it through an import and leverage whatever api jar you have. This was for an eclipse jsp java project.